# Realization of mb_trim with regexes – last symbol doesn't getting removed

Tags: php, regex

I want to trim string with spaces and hyphens

```php
$str = mb_ereg_replace("^([ \-]+)|([ \-]+)$", "", $str);
```

It's pretty ok for texts in english. But when here comes russian the problem suddenly appear: last symbol – either a hyphen or a space – doesn't seem to be removed. And this is only valid for texts that end on russian symbol:

- `наркоман штоле --- -` – a space near `е` will stay;
- `наркоман штоле? lol u mad --- -` – trimmed successfully.

  What's happening?

Comment: Did you set the right charset? Maybe it isn't a plain space char? Have you tried `preg_replace` with the UTF-8 `/u` modifier for that task?

Comment: Definitely use `preg_replace()`, the whole `ereg` functions have been deprecated for ages. And simply use `"/^[ -]+|[ -]+$/"`; no need for those parentheses.

Comment: @mario `preg_replace` works, I just want to know why `mb_ereg_replace` doesn't work. At least in that function I don't have to write `//u` stuff :)

Comment: @TimPietzcker `mb_ereg_*` is not deprecated.

Comment: @mario `preg_replace` doesn't work in that case with `/u` modifier. And it's a plain space char (or a hyphen – what will be on the word's boundary) since I know what I send to the func. And it happens ONLY to russian: if the last non-separator symbol a hieroglyph or a czech letter it works well.

Comment: @mario `mb_detect_encoding` says that the input string is in UTF-8, `mb_regex_encoding` is EUC-JP (o_O) but even if I force it to use UTF-8 nothing happened.